# Json doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to pull random string from database, and then transfer it via json.

But, I am clearly stuck here.

```
<?php


print_r ($return['user_id']);
json_encode($return);


?>
```

And the ajax/js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.getJSON('initiate.php', function(data) {
        $("#chat-area").html(data);
     });   
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure json works just fine. :)

Comment: What does the `print_r` print out?

Comment: Yep. Looks good to me too :).

Comment: `echo`, `print`, that fancy stuff... and don't echo anything before your JSON.

Comment: This doesn't work for me even after removing the echo, print_r prints what it's supposed to print.

Comment: You can inspect all requests being made by your browser by opening your web inspector's "network" tab or equivalent section. There's no need to guess what `initiate.php` is outputting.

Comment: Okay, I can see it there, it's `{0:"2997822413", user_id:"2997822413"}` , The only part I need is the `2997822413` . But it isn't putting it on the `#chat-area` div.

Comment: Nevermind fixed, I wasn't putting the correct element on the `html(data.element)` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It cannot work with:

1. that `print_r` dumping garbage (i.e. non-JSON) to the client and thus the JSON parser
2. you not actually `echo`ing the JSON data.

So, what you want, is this:

```
<?php
// obviously $return needs to contain something. otherwise
// you'll most likely get a notice which is "garbage" too
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

After fixing the server-side code you also need to fix your JavaScript. `data` is an object and thus it does not make much sense to set it as some element's HTML content. You probably want some property of that object:

```
$.getJSON('initiate.php', function(data) {
    $("#chat-area").html(data.whatever);
});
```

Comment: I fixed all of these, but it still doesn't work. I get no output on the index page where the js is.

Comment: Then it's time to check what the PHP script actually outputs and possibly `console.log(data)` in the callback function to see what you get there.

Comment: If I `print_r ($reurn['user_id']);` , it outputs what it's supposed to.

Comment: And also `echo json_encode($return)` outputs `{"0":"2997822413","user_id":"2997822413"}` on the php file , which are the values I need.

Comment: Then you can use `data['0']` or `data.user_id` depending on which value you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
print_r ($return['user_id']);    // invalidates the json output
json_encode($return);            // does not do much...
// should be:
echo json_encode($return);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set content-type and to echo the json only.

```
<?php
    //fill $whatever_you_want
    header('content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($whatever_you_want);
?>
```